# method is not returning anything

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie in Ruby, and could anybody please answer why the following code is not producing any output?:

```
def method(name)
  return "Hello  + #{name}"
end

method("Amy")
```

It's not giving me any result

Comment: The method returns something, but you do not use it. To print the result, just write `puts method("Amy")`

Comment: Note that `method` is actually a reserved method name in Ruby, so be careful when using that.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title you claim that the method doesn't return anything, in the question you say it is not producing any output. Then, again, in your question you say it "is not giving any result". Those are three completely different things. What is your *precise* question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which output? It only returns string. You need to print it or something. Replace last method call with:

```
puts method("Amy")
```

Then you'll notice you probably don't need that `+` because you are already adding `name` as part of string

Answer (score 3):

Well, first, when you do a return in the end of a method it doesn't outputs anything to the screen, the return method is only supposed to give back some value. Let me exemplify, if you do:

```
def method(name)
   return "Hello  + #{name}"
end

hello = method("Amy")
```

Now the return sent the value "Hello + Amy" to the 'hello' variable, so 'hello' has the value of "Hello + Amy". That's what the return do in a method.
Great now to output something in the screen in ruby you need to use puts. For example:

```
def method(name)
   puts "Hello  + #{name}"
end

method("Amy")
```

This will print out "Hello + Amy". And, at last, that plus sign is not necessary if just want to print "Hello Amy"! Hope it helps

Comment: Replacing `return` with `puts` does print _"Hello + Amy"_ but it also changes the methods return value to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use puts or print method to print the result of function.

```
puts(method("Amy"))
```

Or in a variable

```
hello = method("Amy")
puts(hello)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can omit return keyword, Ruby methods ALWAYS return the evaluated result of the last line of the expression unless an explicit return comes before it. If you wanted to explicitly return a value you can use the return keyword Ex. given below :

```
def method(name)
  "Hello "  + "#{name}"
end

p method("Amy")
# Output : "Hello  Amy"

def method(name)
  return "Hello " + "#{name}"
end


p method("Amy")
# Output : "Hello Amy"

def method(name)
   return "Bye " + "#{name}"
  "Hello " + "#{name}"
end

p method("Amy")
# Output "Bye Amy"
```